# libcordova.a error after adding widget extension - ios

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Iam adding a today widget in my Mobile first Project. I am able to run the app in device and simulator. But while performaing a build to distribute it, it's creating a problem. I am able however to make build and distribute before adding an extension.

The error is

> ld: file not found:
>      "Iphone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have shared the valid architecture and other linker flags in the screenshot below. I am using xcode 8.1, cordova 6.0.

[image: Other Linker flags]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Cordova app in MobileFirst 7.1 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for MobileFirst Platform integration:**

It's unclear what is your MobileFirst Platform version or if you're using a Hybrid application generating by MobileFirst Studio or a standard Cordova application.

If you've created a Cordova application using the MobileFirst CLI, this is unrelated to MobileFirst and you need to follow the Cordova guidelines for adding an app extension. Also note that App Extensions in iOS change dramatically between iOS releases. Be sure to consult the iOS documentation...